# How do I split a text file and store them in arrays to use for a template in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a newbie at C and I'm having problems splitting a particular text file and storing the tokens in an array.

This is my txt file called data.txt- to be splitted by "|":

```
Public|Jane|Q|Ms.|600|Maple Street|Your Town|Iowa|12345
Penner|Fred|R|Mr.|123|that Street|Winnipeg|MB|R3T 2N2
Gardner|Mark|E|Mr.|76|The Avenue|Toronto|ON|M5W 1E6
Acton|Hilda|P|Mrs.|66|What Blvd|Winnipeg|MB|R3T 2N2
```

My code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INPUT_LENGTH 128
#define FIELD_LENGTH 30
#define NUM_FIELDS   9

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  FILE *template = NULL;
  FILE *data = NULL;

  char input[INPUT_LENGTH];
  char customerData[NUM_FIELDS][FIELD_LENGTH];
  int  element = 0;
  char *next;
  char ch;

  template = fopen( "template.txt", "r" );
  if ( template != NULL )
  {
    // read in the customers until we're done
    data = fopen( "data.txt", "r" );
    if ( data != NULL )
    {

      //next = strtok(data, "|");
      while(fgets(input, INPUT_LENGTH,data) != EOF){
        next = strtok(input, "|"); //splitting the data stored in input by |
        while(next != NULL){
          strcpy(customerData[element],next);
          //customerData[element++] = next;
          next =strtok(NULL, "|");
          //element++;
        }

        //testing
        for(element=0; element<INPUT_LENGTH; element++){
          printf("%s\n", customerData[element]);
        }
        //printf("%s\n", input );

      }



      fclose( data );
    }

    fclose( template );
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

doing it like this give me an error `array type 'char [30]' is not assignable` and a bunch of garbage output. I need help in knowing what I'm doing wrong in the splitting part.

There are other stuff in the code because the main purpose of my program is to split these files, store the in an array and use each position for my template:
separate template.txt file:

```
Welcome back, $1!
We hope that you and all the members
of the $0 family are constantly
reminding your neighbours there
on $5 to shop with us.
As usual, we will ship your order to
   $3 $1 $2. $0
   $4 $5
   $6, $7 $8
```

for the first token, the output should be like:

```
Welcome back, Jane!
We hope that you and all the members
of the Public family are constantly
reminding your neighbors there
on Maple Street to shop with us.
As usual, we will ship your order to
    Ms. Jane Q. Public
    600 Maple Street
    Your Town, Iowa 12345
```

Comment: Enable compilation warnings, this `fgets(input, INPUT_LENGTH,data) != EOF` should trigger one because `fgets()` returns a pointer and `EOF` is not one.

Comment: yes i enabled it and it did `warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'int')
      while(fgets(input, INPUT_LENGTH,data) != EOF){` @iharob

Comment: And why do you ignore the warning? If I see such warning I immediately search for the `fgets()` documentation and read it throughly.

Comment: I can't seem to point out where its coming from @iharob

Comment: Also you have commented out the incrementing of `element` you will only ever `strcpy` into the first string in your string array.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  (I also use `-Wconversion -std=c99`)    1) returned value from `fgets()` should be comparing to `!= NULL`  2) since `argc` and `argv[]` are not used the signature for main should be `int main( void )`

Comment: when the call to `fopen()` fails, the program just exits, without letting the user know what happened. (this will make the user very unhappy) suggest:  `if( NULL == (template = fopen( "template.txt", "r" ) ) ) { perror( "fopen for reading template.txt failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE >>); } // implied else, fopen successful ....  The call to `perror()` will, on stderr, display the enclosed text + the error message from the system as to why the fopen() failed

Answer (score 0):

the following code drops reference to the `template.txt` file as it is not used in the code.

An appropriate struct is defined for the customer data

each field is extracted from the input and copied into the array of customer data

the 'test' code outputs each field from the customer data array.

error checks are implemented and appropriate action taken.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strtok()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define INPUT_LENGTH   (128)
#define FIELD_LENGTH   (30)
#define NUM_FIELDS     (9)
#define MAX_CUSTOMERS  (20)

struct customer
{
    char lastName[ FIELD_LENGTH ];
    char firstName[ FIELD_LENGTH ];
    char initial[ FIELD_LENGTH ];
    char salutation[ FIELD_LENGTH ];
    char streetNumber[ FIELD_LENGTH ];
    char streetName[ FIELD_LENGTH ];
    char cityName[ FIELD_LENGTH ];
    char stateName[FIELD_LENGTH ];
    char zipCode[ FIELD_LENGTH ];
};

int main( void )
{
    struct customer customerData[ MAX_CUSTOMERS ];

    FILE *fp = NULL;

    char input[INPUT_LENGTH];

    int  element = 0;
    char *token = NULL;

    // read in the customers until we're done
    if( NULL == (fp = fopen( "data.txt", "r" ) ) )
    { // fopen failed
        perror( "fopen to read data.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( element < MAX_CUSTOMERS && fgets(input, INPUT_LENGTH, fp))
    {
        if( NULL != (token = strtok(input, "|") ) ) //splitting the data stored in input by |
            strcpy( customerData[element].lastName, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( NULL != (token = strtok( NULL, "|") ) )
            strcpy( customerData[element].firstName, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( NULL != (token = strtok( NULL, "|" ) ) )
            strcpy( customerData[element].initial, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( NULL != (token = strtok( NULL, "|" ) ) )
            strcpy( customerData[element].salutation, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( NULL != (token = strtok( NULL, "|" ) ) )
            strcpy( customerData[element].streetNumber, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( NULL != (token = strtok( NULL, "|" ) ) )
            strcpy( customerData[element].streetName, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( NULL != (token = strtok( NULL, "|" ) ) )
            strcpy( customerData[element].cityName, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( NULL != (token = strtok( NULL, "|" ) ) )
            strcpy( customerData[element].stateName, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        if( NULL != (token = strtok( NULL, "|" ) ) )
            strcpy( customerData[element].zipCode, token );
        else
        { // invalid file format
            fprintf( stderr, "line %d, contains invalid format\n", element);
            fclose( fp );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        element++;
    } // end while

    //testing
#if 0
    // code with bug
    for(int i = 0; i < element; i++)
    {
        printf("lastName:    %s\n", customerData[element].lastName);
        printf("firstName:   %s\n", customerData[element].firstName);
        printf("initial:     %s\n", customerData[element].initial);
        printf("salutation:  %s\n", customerData[element].salutation);
        printf("streeNumber: %s\n", customerData[element].streetNumber);
        printf("streetName:  %s\n", customerData[element].streetName);
        printf("cityName:    %s\n", customerData[element].cityName);
        printf("stateName:   %s\n", customerData[element].stateName);
        printf("zipCode:     %s\n", customerData[element].zipCode);
    }
#else
    // corrected code
    for(int i = 0; i < element; i++)
    {
        printf("lastName:    %s\n", customerData[i].lastName);
        printf("firstName:   %s\n", customerData[i].firstName);
        printf("initial:     %s\n", customerData[i].initial);
        printf("salutation:  %s\n", customerData[i].salutation);
        printf("streeNumber: %s\n", customerData[i].streetNumber);
        printf("streetName:  %s\n", customerData[i].streetName);
        printf("cityName:    %s\n", customerData[i].cityName);
        printf("stateName:   %s\n", customerData[i].stateName);
        printf("zipCode:     %s\n", customerData[i].zipCode);
    }
#endif


    fclose( fp );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: the code does not print the data along with the variable name

Comment: let me take another look and modify my answer

Comment: @T--,   The corrected code is now posted,  The bug was using `element` for the index rather than `i` into the array of data